# Where I can ask questions regarding Samsung mobile phone software?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I tried using SuperUser but, as you know, they close such questions. Where can I seek help on such a matter?

I need some utility software, like Ultramp3, for Samsung mobile phones.

Comment: What are you asking about? Where to buy? How to program? Be specific.

Comment: @hardcodeuser, thanx for editions :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should looking-for-resources questions go?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128158/where-should-looking-for-resources-questions-go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [Darkforest Group forums](http://darkforestgroup.com/forum/index.php)

Comment: Thanx .. for the link .. I found somethings related there ..

Answer (score 5):

The [Samsung support site](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/main/supportMain.do)?

Comment: I need some other utility softwares than those which are available with the samsung mobile .. Just wnted to ask where I can get them ..

Thanx for the response .. :-)

Answer (score -3):

There are various community in which you can discuss your problems. You can ask question and get the solution also. You can also check at Samsung India site in its support option.