# Where should looking-for-resources questions go?

Tags: discussion

Questions like *looking for css templates*, *blog templates*, *icons ...* In general, *resources* (let's leave the licensing terms aside for now) which you might need when building a project of your own. Where should those questions go?

They're definitely not on-topic on ***Stack'***, ***SuperUser*** maybe although I doubt it. ***Webapps?*** Hmm, probably not.

***Is there a place where they would be on-topic on the SE network?***

Comment: Resource requests are off-topic on most SE sites. Not sure if there exists an except that would apply here.

Answer (score 16):

> Is there a place where they would be on-topic on the SE network?

[NOPE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJP1DphOWPs&feature=youtube_gdata_player)

Unfortunately "list questions" which ask where someone can find a good X are not really on topic for any Stack Exchange site.  In fact, the community is [quite clear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126583/would-a-shopping-stackexchange-do-any-good) in their dislike for such content :)

The main problem with these questions is that they tend to lead to long lists—with lots of concomitant noise—and are constantly out of date.

Comment: The community has also made it quite clear that they are not entirely opposed to "list good stuff" kind of questions, as we all know from the infamous [C++ book list question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1) (or should I say incident?).